# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error for java net beans

Tags: javascript, servlets

How to fix this error?

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1

Comment: can you post some of the code causing this error?

Comment: <%
               int i=1;
        MyCon x=new MyCon();
        Connection c=x.tcon();
    
        PreparedStatement pst=c.prepareStatement("select * from category");
     
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){   i++; %>

Comment: You are trying to get something from a DB. Does the connection work? Please update the question with the formatted code. It seems wrong in the comment.